# Using Python nested if statement for labels in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, labeling, python-parser

I am trying to use python to write a label expression that will display a specific set of labels based on nested if statments. The expression should result in a 4 line label if the value is greater than zero. It should be a 3 line label if the value is equal to zero, basically removing the zero from the label.

```
def FindLabel( [OPERATOR], [WELLNAME], [WELLNUM], [EURMBOE_LM], [PERMIT_DAT], [SPUD_DATE_], [COMP_DATE_], [WELL_STATU]):
    lbl = [OPERATOR] +'\n' + [WELLNAME] +'_'+ [WELLNUM]
    if float([EURMBOE_LM] >0):
        if [WELL_STATU] == "Permit":
            return lbl + '\n' + [PERMIT_DAT] + '\n' + [EURMBOE_LM]
        elif [WELL_STATU] =="DUC":
            return lbl + '\n' + [SPUD_DATE_] + '\n' + [EURMBOE_LM]
        elif [WELL_STATU] =="PDP":
            return lbl + '\n' + [COMP_DATE_] + '\n' + [EURMBOE_LM]
    else:
        if [WELL_STATU] =="Permit":
            return lbl + '\n' + [PERMIT_DAT]
        elif [WELL_STATU] =="DUC":
            return lbl + '\n' + [SPUD_DATE_]
        elif [WELL_STATU] =="PDP":
            return lbl + '\n' + [COMP_DATE_]
```

Is the expression wrong?

See pic of labels still displaying the 0[image]

Comment: Shouldnt `if float([EURMBOE_LM] >0)` be `if float([EURMBOE_LM]) >0`? You cant convert True/False to float

Comment: You may also be able to accomplish this using [label classes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm).

Comment: Besides BERA's suggestion, you may also need to !COLUMN_NAME!.